# WCF Self Host Via Https Fails

Tags: c#, wcf, host, self

So I am pretty stuck here. I've always been able to host WCF apps with no problem over http. I can setup https WCF apps in IIS. But when I'm trying to use a self hosted https wcf app this has been nothing but a nightmare. **I am running both the client and self hosted service on the same computer**. Also, the service opens each time I run it with no errors. It's reported state is open. When I try to connect with the client (which is activating the service via channel factories) it crashes with the SSL/TLS error as described below. I've been at this for about 2 days now and can't get it to work :(

I have tried following several guides such as (but not limited to) the ones here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/10/selfhosting-a-wcf-service-over-https.aspx as well as here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx. The first document I follow it to the letter and at the end when the author says "And that's it! now we can call the program and it will invoke the service" it doesn't. It gives me an error:

> "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".

So I tried a slightly different approach upon coming on to the second article. I tried to use an existing certification already listed for my server (which is stored under personal certifcations). I copied the thumbprint and registered it with the port creating my own app id. That didn't work so I thought well lets try to force the client certificate thumbprint on both the service and the client by specifying the client credentials and looking it up via thumbprint like so:

```
factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.LocalMachine, 
    StoreName.My,          
    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, 
    "The actual thumbprint is here in my code");
```

I still get the same results. What am I missing? Here is the code for both the service and the client.

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using HttpsSelfHost;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string address = "https://localhost:8007/HelloWorldSvc";
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

            try
            {
                ChannelFactory<IHelloWorldSvc> factory = new ChannelFactory<IHelloWorldSvc>(binding, address);
                factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
                    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "f80e16f75e805b951e6099979f6dcea56bce3273");
                IHelloWorldSvc client = factory.CreateChannel();
                Console.WriteLine("Invoking service.");
                string str = client.HelloWorld();
                Console.WriteLine("Returned: {0}", str);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace HttpsSelfHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string address = "https://localhost:8007/HelloWorldSvc";
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldSvc)))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloWorldSvc), binding, address);
                host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
                    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "f80e16f75e805b951e6099979f6dcea56bce3273");
                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Host is: {0}. Press enter to close.", host.State);
                Console.ReadLine();
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you still getting the same error after adding the certificate validation?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your client is rejecting the certificate during the negotiation process. I suspect that the certificate you bound on the port that the host is listening at is self-signed.

Here's something that you can use on the client in the testing environment and possibly production if you're okay with certificate pinning.

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the Certificate Validation Policy for the Client
/// </summary>
public static void SetCertificatePolicy()
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback 
                                          += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
}

/// <summary>
/// Allows for validation of SSL conversations with the server. 
/// </summary>
private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, 
                                        X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
{
    if (cert.GetCertHashString() == "Your Certificate SHA1 HashString")
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
       string text = "Failed to establish secure channel for SSL/TLS." 
                     + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                     "Connection with server has been disallowed.";
       MessageBox.Show(text, @"SSL Validation Failure", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I get off of work I will try to look into that I haven't heard of certificate pinning. I am using a self-signed certificate. Thanks so far for the advice! :)

Comment: Did you try this out on the client?

Comment: I did and it gave me the info I needed. The certificate was in lower case >< The service wanted it in upper case. However, when I move the client code to my local iis web service it throws the ssl error again. Why would it do this? Both the self hosted service and the client code being used in a web hosted wcf service are on the same machine.

Comment: And I will point out I literally copied and pasted the code I was originally using.

Comment: I'm thinking it is a permission issue with IIS not letting the services communicate with locahost on oany port or something. I don't see else why the service call would fail when the same code works in a console app, just doesn't work in a web service being hosted in IIS on the same machine. I've been researching possible issues but so far have yielded no results.

Comment: I'm looking into the issue as well. I'm not too familiar with hosting via IIS (I Self-Host all of my services) - but I'm willing to work on resolving the issue as long as you are. :-)